# 2D array static initialisation in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, static, initialization, static-initialization

How to initialise the below 2D static array ?
The following works:

```
static int[][] arr = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
static int[][] arr = new int[][]{ {1,2}, {3,4} };
```

but what if I want to initialise with a larger data maybe using a for loop ?

```
class Abc {
    static int[][] arr;
}
```

Comment: where is the issue? Are you asking for how to write a loop or how to add a values in 2-D array?

Comment: @user3218114 For someone with a relatively high reputation, I'm surprised you haven't changed your default usernames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to initialize the array in a static initializer block. Of course, it's not very interesting, since all the integers in the array are identical.

```
class Abc {
    static int[][] arr;

    static {
       arr = new int[100][300];
       for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
           for (int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++) {
               arr[i][j] = 7;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a static initializer block. You can see the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).